# Should I use Request.IsAuthenticated or WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated with MVC4 Simple membership?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using a MVC4 database with Simple membership. In the sample template 
they use the following:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
    <text>
        Hello, @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "username", title = "Manage" })!
        @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" })) {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
        }
```

On other sites I see this:

```
@if(WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)
{
  <p>Welcome, @WebSecurity.CurrentUserName</p>
  <p><a href="@Href("~/logout")">Log out</a></p>
}
```

Can someone tell me what is the difference between these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Request.IsAuthenticated**

I believe that if you are using the Windows authentication. If the request is send by an authenticated user, this will always true. In this the user and groups etc are handled by Windows Active Directory or User accounts in your machine.

**WebSecurwity.IsAuthenticated**

This I believe that while using Membership provider, we can able to CRUD operations for users.
Please visit the below url to obtain more info.
http://www.mikepope.com/blog/displayblog.aspx?permalink=2240

Comment: Thanks but the page u show is the one that made me wonder why it's different from the standard MVC4 template. So I still don't understand why use one or the other. As far as I see it both are shown as being used with SimpleMembership so I am wondering what is the difference.

Comment: @Melina let me check in detail. I m busy for some more days.I will try  reply you ASAP. Thanks :)